# I am create registation form. But why display whitelable error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am creating an insert page for registration. Users can complete the registration form and click the submit button. After displaying a white-label error. What is the problem?
How can solve that problem?
Used thyelf

**Member Controller**

```
package com.booking.system.controller;

import com.booking.system.entity.Doctor;
import com.booking.system.entity.Member;
import com.booking.system.service.DoctorService;
import com.booking.system.service.MemberService;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super;
import org.apache.catalina.Store;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MemberController {

    public MemberService memberService;

    public MemberController(MemberService memberService) {
        super();
        this.memberService = memberService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/members")
    public String MemberPage(){
        return "members";
    }

    //html page name
    @GetMapping("/member_register")
    public String showSignUpForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("members", new Member());
        return "member_register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/members")
    public String Member (@ModelAttribute("member") Member member){
        memberService.saveMember(member);
        return "redirect:/members";
    }
}
```

**Member(entity)**

```
package com.booking.system.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "members")
public class Member {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;


    public Member(){

    }

    public Member(Long id, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String password, String phoneNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


}
```

**MemberSevice**

```
 package com.booking.system.service;
    
    import com.booking.system.entity.Member;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public interface MemberService {
    
        Member saveMember(Member member);
    }

**MemberServiceImpl**
    package com.booking.system.service;
    
    import com.booking.system.entity.Member;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public interface MemberService {
    
        Member saveMember(Member member);
    }

**member_register.html**
    <!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Member Registration </title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
              integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Member Registration</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="@{/members}" method="POST" th:object="${members}" class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label-col-4">Email address</label>
                <input type="email"
                       class="form-control"
                       th:field="*{email}"
                       placeholder="Enter email">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label-col-4">First Name</label>
                <input type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       th:field="*{firstName}" required
                       placeholder="Enter First Name">
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label-col-4">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       th:field="*{lastName}" required
                       placeholder="Enter Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label-col-4">Password</label>
                <input type="password"
                       class="form-control"
                       th:field ="*{password}"
                       placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label-col-4">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       th:field="*{phoneNumber}"
                       placeholder="Enter Phone Number" required>
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>

**member.html**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Member Page</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome Member</h1>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <h3><a th:href="@{/member_register}">Register</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bookingSystem</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookingsystem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Booking_System</name>
    <description>Booking System for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**MemberRepository**

```
package com.booking.system.repository;

import com.booking.system.entity.Member;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface MemberRepository  extends JpaRepository<Member, Long> {
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnNkS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work correctly for you:

```
<form action="members" method="POST" th:object="${members}" class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
```

Comment: Thank you. this error is I am not using "th:" for form action.